# Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping - grouping column as a normal column

Tags: datatables, grouping

I am using Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping:
http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/
and I'd  like to have this exact style but with the difference to have as a column the "Rendering engine", like all the others.
I would appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exposed configuration on how the code selects the grouping column.
Then I think you should try to put the `Rendering engine` at the first column in order to check if this JS code does group only by the first column it finds on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax for specifying which column should be grouped, where an index of 0 would be the first column.

```
$("#myTable").dataTable().rowGrouping({iGroupingColumnIndex:5});
```